# TC4422 output doesn't go low

Tags: mosfet, mosfet-driver

I'm trying to test a TC4422 mosfet driver with a simple circuit shown below. Input is a 1kHz square wave 10 Vpp.

[image]

For some reason the output across the 10k resistor stays high all the time (~VCC) no matter what I connect to the TC4422 input. The logic low voltage (max) is specd at 0.8 V in the datasheet. The output doesn't go low even when I ground the input pin. Can someone explain what's wrong here?

Any suggestions will be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: this might sound strange, but: Did you connect your TC4422 the right way around, i.e. is the dot on the package really on the VCC side, and not accidentally on the GND side?

Comment: Where did you buy the chip from?

Comment: Turns out it's just bad parts. I ordered 10 pieces off AliExpress (yes, I know ...) and out of the 10 only 2 are good. I made this post because initially I had tried 3 different ones and all had the same behavior. But when testing the remaining ones I saw that some also exhibited other failure modes. I will inform the seller of this obviously, normally the parts that I order from there work fine.